# Javascript, Background color change not working

Tags: javascript, html

I've been working on this little project, and I've been trying to make the background color change onclick. But for some reason it won't work.
The part that I'm trying to use is `p.style.background ='$color'`

> HTML (Might be a little weird, cause it's written in pug, and this is compiled)

```
<div id="MainContainer">
<div id="Left">
  <p id="FontSettings">Font settings</p>
  <p id="Font">Ab</p>
  <p id="FontName">
    Roboto <span id="FontWeight">Normal</span></p>
</div>
<div id="Right"><sup id="StandardFontSup">Standard font</sup>
  <select id="FontSelect" onchange="EchoFontName(); changeFont (this);">
    <option value="Roboto">Roboto</option>
    <option value="Lato">Lato</option>
    <option value="Raleway">Raleway</option>
    <option value="Ubuntu">Ubuntu</option>
  </select><sup id="StyleSup">Style</sup>
  <select id="StyleSelect" onchange="EchoStyleName(); changeStyle (this);">
    <option value="Thin">Thin</option>
    <option value="Light">Light</option>
    <option value="Normal" selected="selected">Normal</option>
    <option value="Bold">Bold</option>
  </select>
  <div id="ColorTilesContainer">
    <div id="blue" onclick="blueCheckToggle()"></div>
    <div id="blueCheck" onclick="blueCheckToggle()"></div>
    <div id="orange" onclick="orangeCheckToggle()"></div>
    <div id="orangeCheck" onclick="orangeCheckToggle()"></div>
    <div id="green" onclick="greenCheckToggle()"></div>
    <div id="greenCheck" onclick="greenCheckToggle()"></div>
    <div id="teal" onclick="tealCheckToggle()"></div>
    <div id="tealCheck" onclick="tealCheckToggle()"></div>
    <div id="custom" onclick=""></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> Javascript

```
var changeFont = function(font){
  console.log(font.value)
    document.getElementById("MainContainer").style.fontFamily = font.value;
}
function EchoFontName() {
  var f = document.getElementById("FontName");
  var FontNameVar = document.getElementById("FontSelect").value;
  f.textContent = FontNameVar;
}
var changeStyle = function(font){
  console.log(font.value)
    document.getElementById("MainContainer").style.fontWeight = font.value;
}
function EchoStyleName() {
  var f = document.getElementById("FontWeight");
  var FontNameVar = document.getElementById("StyleSelect").value;
  f.textContent = FontNameVar;
}
var x = document.getElementById("blueCheck");
var t = document.getElementById("orangeCheck");
var r = document.getElementById("greenCheck");
var l = document.getElementById("tealCheck");
var p = document.getElementById("Left");

function blueCheckToggle() {
  if (x.style.opacity === "0") {
  x.style.opacity = "1";
  t.style.opacity = "0";
  r.style.opacity = "0";
  l.style.opacity = "0";
  p.style.background = "$lightblue";
  }
  else {
    x.style.opacity = "0";
  }
}
function orangeCheckToggle() {
  if (t.style.opacity === "0") {
  x.style.opacity = "0";
  t.style.opacity = "1";
  r.style.opacity = "0";
  l.style.opacity = "0";
  p.style.background = "$orange";
  }
  else {
    t.style.opacity = "0";
  }
}
function greenCheckToggle() {
  if (r.style.opacity === "0") {
  x.style.opacity = "0";
  t.style.opacity = "0";
  r.style.opacity = "1";
  l.style.opacity = "0";
  p.style.background = "$green";
  }
  else {
    r.style.opacity = "0";
  }
}
function tealCheckToggle() {
  if (l.style.opacity === "0") {
  x.style.opacity = "0";
  t.style.opacity = "0";
  r.style.opacity = "0";
  l.style.opacity = "1";
  p.style.background = "$teal";
  }
  else {
    p.style.opacity = "0";
  }
}
```

You can also visit my codepen, to see the complete project, and fork it.
https://codepen.io/JorisMertz/pen/dKRNBv?editors=0010

Thanks in advance! Joris.

Comment: Why do you put a dollar before color names? It's meant to be parsed by something? Are you sure it's parsed?

Comment: It is not going to pull from SASS variables  that is what you are after. Why are you not just adding classes?

Comment: What are the $ signs next to color name? Have you tried without it?

Comment: I'm using scss, It's an variable color (It's fixed thanks for the help @epascarello)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using Sass variables, And since it adds the style inline, it doesn't pull the variables. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the css property 'background-color' you need to use JS DOM CSS [W3School HTML DOM Style Object](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_style.asp):

`p.style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";`

Comment: Pretty sure you don't want `style.style`.

Comment: Nope this doesn't change anything.

Comment: My bad, removed the extra .style.